# Obtaining the bias column from a boot object output in R

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to obtain the bias column from a boot object? I cannot seem to get this out.

```
    boot1

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = head(hiv.df, 20), statistic = treatment, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
        original      bias    std. error
t1*   0.16509434  0.10624368   0.2451772
t2*   0.05977011  0.19175568   0.2454798
t3*   0.55162242 -0.28773621   0.2489987
t4*   0.20318725  0.05920368   0.2512117
t5*   0.57425743 -0.31218624   0.2503913
t6*   0.16274510  0.09341908   0.2556413
t7*   0.04244032  0.21688713   0.2549574
t8*   0.22089552  0.04170836   0.2493027
t9*   0.19024390  0.06991568   0.2512938
t10*  0.13731343  0.12995791   0.2482272
t11*  0.14216867  0.11484235   0.2547241
t12* -0.07584270  0.32486333   0.2480479
t13*  0.63716814 -0.37496656   0.2530745
t14*  0.50000000 -0.23611951   0.2513210
t15*  0.65234375 -0.38778582   0.2546094
t16*  0.09121622  0.17503414   0.2518138
t17*  0.02811245  0.22923011   0.2435892
t18*  0.42244224 -0.17894536   0.2519152
t19*  0.64285714 -0.38258403   0.2534739
t20* -0.20000000  0.45407128   0.2454800
```

I have tried boot1$bias for example, but this simply does not work.

I not know how to do this without stackexchange complaining that I have too much code. Is there a way around this?

```
treatment <- function(x, i){
 return((x[i,3] - x[i,2])/x[i,2])
}

boot1 <- boot(head(hiv.df, 20), treatment, R=1000)
```

There is the code.

```
> hiv.df
   Patient Baseline OneYear
1        1     2.12    2.47
2        2     4.35    4.61
3        3     3.39    5.26
4        4     2.51    3.02
5        5     4.04    6.36
6        6     5.10    5.93
7        7     3.77    3.93
8        8     3.35    4.09
9        9     4.10    4.88
10      10     3.35    3.81
11      11     4.15    4.74
12      12     3.56    3.29
```

There is some of the data. There is actually 40 rows just like this.

No hint of bias and std.error columns in here:

```
List of 11
 $ t0       : num [1:20] 0.1651 0.0598 0.5516 0.2032 0.5743 ...
 $ t        : num [1:1000, 1:20] 0.5516 0.1902 -0.2 0.6372 0.0281 ...
 $ R        : num 1000
 $ data     :'data.frame':  20 obs. of  3 variables:
  ..$ Patient : int [1:20] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
  ..$ Baseline: num [1:20] 2.12 4.35 3.39 2.51 4.04 5.1 3.77 3.35 4.1 3.35 ...
  ..$ OneYear : num [1:20] 2.47 4.61 5.26 3.02 6.36 5.93 3.93 4.09 4.88 3.81 ...
 $ seed     : int [1:626] 403 74 -1132582028 -613240578 -640033619 1312044266 1708814265 1558968915 -345709414 842125154 ...
 $ statistic:function (x, i)  
  ..- attr(*, "srcref")= 'srcref' int [1:8] 1 14 3 1 14 1 1 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "srcfile")=Classes 'srcfilecopy', 'srcfile' <environment: 0x000000001e7ce220> 
 $ sim      : chr "ordinary"
 $ call     : language boot(data = head(hiv.df, 20), statistic = treatment, R = 1000)
 $ stype    : chr "i"
 $ strata   : num [1:20] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ weights  : num [1:20] 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 0.05 ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "boot"
 - attr(*, "boot_type")= chr "boot"
```

I'm using the boot package:

```
> dput(head(hiv.df, 20))
structure(list(Patient = 1:20, Baseline = c(2.12, 4.35, 3.39, 
2.51, 4.04, 5.1, 3.77, 3.35, 4.1, 3.35, 4.15, 3.56, 3.39, 1.88, 
2.56, 2.96, 2.49, 3.03, 2.66, 3), OneYear = c(2.47, 4.61, 5.26, 
3.02, 6.36, 5.93, 3.93, 4.09, 4.88, 3.81, 4.74, 3.29, 5.55, 2.82, 
4.23, 3.23, 2.56, 4.31, 4.37, 2.4)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you provide some data to reproduce your output? Include the output `dput(head(hiv.df, 20))` at the end of your question. Also name all packages you've used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing we assign the name to the function call of boot

```
b <- boot(.....)
```

you can calculate the first bias using

```
> mean(b$t[,1]) - b$t0[1])
```

[1] 0.10624368

and the second bias using

```
> mean(b$t[,2]) - b$t0[2])
```

[1] 0.19175568